# Connes fusion and the composition of completely positive maps

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N$ be a type $II_{1}$-factor with trace $\tau$.

An $N-N$ correspondence is a Hilbert $N$-bimodule $H$ where the left and right actions are both ultraweakly continuous. Equivalently, a correspondence is given by a *-homomorphism of $N$ into an amplification of $N$. (See Popa's *correspondences* INCREST preprint for more detail.)

The Connes fusion $H \otimes_{N} K$ of correspondences $H$ and $K$ is also called the composition of $H$ and $K$, since it in the "amplification picture" described above, $H \otimes_{N} K$ is isomorphic to the composition of an amplification of the *-homomorphism  associated to $K$ with the *-homomorphism associated to $H$.

Furthermore, the [Stinespring construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinespring_factorization_theorem) allows us to associate a (cyclic) correspondence $H_{\phi}$ to a completely positive map $\phi$ on $N$, and all cyclic correspondences are of this form, i.e. we can recover the completely positive map from a (unit) cyclic vector. If $\phi_{\xi}$ (resp. $\phi_{\eta}$) denotes the c.p. map associated to a cyclic vector $\xi$ (resp. $\eta$), then it is straightforward to prove that $H_{\phi_{\eta} \circ \phi_{\xi}} \cong H_{\phi_{\xi \otimes_{N} \eta}}$.

It is not true, in general, that $H_{\phi}\otimes_{N} H_{\psi} \cong H_{\psi \circ \phi}$ for normal completely positive maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ on $N$.

> Question: Precisely when is $H_{\phi}\otimes_{N} H_{\psi} \cong H_{\psi \circ \phi}$?

It is true if the maps are unital *-homomorphisms, but is false when both maps are $\tau$. Are there any other cases where the statement is true?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Stinespring construction. Could you add a reference (or explanation) please?

Comment: @André: Essentially, it is a GNS analogue where you use the CP map $\phi$ instead of a state. In our case, equip the algebraic tensor product N \otimes N with the sesquilinear form $\langle x_{1} \otimes y_{1}, x_{2} \otimes y_{2} \rangle=\tau(y_{2}^{*}\phi(x_{2}^{*}x_{1})y_{1})$ separate and complete, prove things are bounded, etc... This all can be found in Popa's preprint. A nicer explanation of the general construction is located in Paulsen's book: *Completely bounded maps and operator algebras*. Let me know if this did the trick. Thanks for thinking about my problem!

Comment: BTW: It may be that I am asking precisely when $\xi \otimes_{N} \eta$ is a cyclic vector, but I hope there is something more I'm not seeing.

Comment: It may be revealing to look at the non-factor case $N\cong L^\infty[0,1]$.  Then your normal c.p. map $\phi$ is determined by a measure $\eta_\phi$ on $[0,1]^2$ with the property that the push-forwards of $\eta_\phi$ onto the two coordinate directions are Lebesgue-abs. continuous.  If I am not mistaken, then $\xi\otimes_N \eta$ is cyclic iff either $\xi$ or $\eta$ (densely) generates $H_\phi$ (resp., $H_\psi$) as a left (right) module. If you disintegrate $d\eta_\phi(x,y)=d\mu_x(y) dx$, the condition is that $\mu_x$ is atomic x-a.e. 

It may be more fun to ask for isom. up to multiplicity.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped: te condition is that $mu_x$ has support $<= 1$ point $x$-a.e.

Comment: Thanks for these comments Dima. I'm not sure yet how to see the fusion in terms of the measures, yet. I'm not sure how the disintegration you mention encodes the fusion. Is it clear that H_{\phi_{\xi}} \otimes H_{\phi_{\eta}} is itself cyclic? (And are we then disintegrating the measure associated to the c.p. map of this as a cyclic correspondence?)

Comment: No, $H_{\phi_\xi} \otimes H_{\phi_\eta}$ just about never has a cyclic vector even in this abelian case $N=L^\infty[0,1]$.  What I was saying is that the condition on cyclicity of $\xi\otimes\eta$ can be more readily seen in the abelian case, where there is a nice picture for the correspondences.  Very roughly, you need either $H_\phi$ or $H_\psi$ to be of dimension <=1 as left (right) $N$-modules, which translates into the condition that the module is the compression of a module associated to a homomorphism.

Comment: @Dima: I have to sit and work this out, but your comments have been very helpful. Thanks again.